# How to scroll a banner when I scroll a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually I want to scroll a banner when I scroll page in HTML.

And it will scroll in the fix length.

```
<div class="right-featured-panel2"> 
  <a href="uhaul.com/"; target="_blank"><img src="faq_files/uhaul.jpg" class="banner-div" alt="" width="247px" height="323px"></a>
</div> 
<div class="clr"></div>
```

Comment: You cannot do this with PHP as your problem seems to be a client side one.

Comment: Scroll the banner in which direction? Is the banner an img/div/flash element? Define "scroll"?

Comment: A live example is _always_ appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a PHP question! It's client-side prerogative to manage that kind of functionality. I'll edit your tags.

But in CSS you can give your element **fixed position**. It will be positioned relative to your window. Whenever you scroll your window it will scroll too.

```
#myBanner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: <div class="right-featured-panel2">
 <a href="http://www.uhaul.com/" target="_blank">
 <img src="faq_files/uhaul.jpg" class="banner-div" alt="" width="247px" height="323px"></a></div>
    <div class="clr"></div> my div tage is this how i set this css set please

Comment: I will not help you with that, I gave you an idea, I'm not going to teach you CSS here =). there are millions of tutorials out there.